# PIN longer than 16 digits

Tags: lock-screens, password

I was wondering if there was any way to use an unlock PIN longer than 16 digits on android lollipop - in the settings it allows you to enter a PIN less than 17 digits. I would like to stay away from 3rd party lock screens if possible. I am running resurrection remix (Lollipop 5.1.1).

Thanks

Comment: Appears to be hard-coded: see [L108](https://github.com/ResurrectionRemix/Resurrection_packages_apps_Settings/blob/lollipop5.1/src/com/android/settings/ChooseLockPassword.java#L108) and [L318](https://github.com/ResurrectionRemix/Resurrection_packages_apps_Settings/blob/lollipop5.1/src/com/android/settings/ChooseLockPassword.java#L318)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Far as I know, **no.** Now of course wait for more answers but far as I know, if it is set to be 16 characters max it means it is a 128 bit variable. If that is all Android has saved for the PIN, then that is that.

Comment: It would help if you  explain the reason for mentioning "*it means it is a 128 bit variable*". Alternatively, tell us what is it about and why does it matter? Perhaps, something in the source code , or maybe a security policy for Android, or something else?

Comment: @Firelord I am not a developer so I don't know very deeply about security measurements of Android. I know that PIN is **not** meant as the ultimate security tool though. Anyone who had enough time and required tools can certainly crack the PIN code eventually. Let's not get sidetracked though. Far as I know, when you set a PIN code, the combination you picked is assigned to a variable with a pre-defined size. You can't assign a literal value greater than the variable can take or it will fail. Youtube used a 32bit counter and Gangnam style was watched more times than it could take and it broke.