# How do I set a device password longer than seventeen characters?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lock-screens, password

The stock-Android device security settings restrict the length of passwords (and PINs) to seventeen characters. When I first got my device, I worked around this by using Android Device Manager to lock it. Now, I'd like to change the password, but the device itself still refuses to set anything exceeding that limit, and ADM just uses the existing password (despite prompting me for a new one). What's another way to bypass this limit, without disabling disk encryption as a side effect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PIN longer than 16 digits](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/129882/pin-longer-than-16-digits)

Comment: @Firelord Not really. That asker seems to have accepted an answer that basically says not to treat a PIN|password as any kind of substantial security mechanism, which is exactly what I'm trying to do.